# Find order $3$ element in $\mathbb{Z}_{67}^*$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am computing possible maps from $\mathbb{Z}_3 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{67}^*$ for the purpose of classifying $\mathbb{Z}_{67} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_{3}$.

I understand I just need to find one element of order $3$ and the only other one is its square.

Using brute force, one can find $29$ to be the smallest correct answer. But since finding primitive root modulo $n$ is an open problem, is there a trick one can use to tackle the situation here without checking whether $g^3=e$ for all candidate $g$s up to $29$?

Comment: For a way different from the one in Noobie's answer you can do the following. Recall (from complex roots of unity) that the numbers $(-1\pm\sqrt{-3})/2$ have multiplicative order three. You can take advantage of this here, as $-3\equiv64\pmod{67}$. Surely you know what the square root of $64$ is :-) Then calculate $(-1\pm 8)/2$ modulo $67$. Division by $2$ means the same thing as multiplying by $2^{-1}=34$.

Comment: (cont'd) But you may be better off by, instead of calculating $(-1\pm 8)\cdot2^{-1}$, to calculate $(-1\pm 8+67)/2$. Modulo $67$ it obviously won't make any difference, but because we are used to dividing even integers by two, this will feel easier :-)

Answer (score 3):

First you could get a generator. Since $\varphi (67)=66=3\cdot 2\cdot 11$, you just need to check whether $g^6,g^{22}=e$ and $g^{33}=e$, for each candidate $g$, by a well-known theorem. If neither is the case then you have a generator, call it $\hat g$.

Then $\hat g^{22}$ will have order $3$.

> $2$ is primitive,  and $2^{22}=37, 2^{44}=29$.

> Here's how I got $2^{22}\pmod{67}$:  $$\begin{align}2^{22}&\equiv 4^{11}\\ &\equiv (4^3)^3\cdot 4^2\\ &\equiv (64)^3\cdot 4^2\\ &\equiv (-3)^3\cdot 16\\ &\equiv-9\cdot 48\\ &\equiv-9\cdot(-19)\\ &\equiv3\cdot 57\\ &\equiv 3\cdot(-10)\\ &\equiv-30\\ &\equiv 37.\end{align}$$

Comment: This is certainly a convenient way to find a generator. But a "brute force" strategy one can use is to check whether $g^3 = e$ for each candidate $g$. If so, then $g$ must be of order $3$. I was wondering if there is a more convenient way than that.

Comment: Well,  isn't this better than possibly checking $66$ (or so)  cubes?  $2^{22}\pmod{67}$ isn't very difficult to compute.

Comment: By checking $2^{22} (mod 67)$, do you mean by hand? Like directly take $22nd$ power and divide by $67$?

Comment: Yes,  but there's shortcuts.  I'm a little error prone.  There are guys around here who are great at it.  It's not that hard.   Should I show you?

Comment: Also, where can I find the well known theorem? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Sure.   I have it on page $108$ of Vinogradov,  "Elements of Number Theory".  This book, btw, also has tables of primitive roots and indices in the back.

Comment: Using the (known) cyclicity of $\Bbb{Z}_{67}^*$ is the key to this approach. Basically you can take a random element and raise it to power $22$. If you don't get $1$, you are done. $2$ is the simplest "random" number :-)